# Comparing strings in pipeline plugin jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am building a process-pipeline with the pipeline-plugin for jenkins. I have some jobs which I have to trigger. To decide which next step I have to use, I write a return code in a file. After this, I read this file and make a decision. But the comparing does not work.

```
def returnCode = readFile 'return'

//IP in Datenbank
if ( returnCode == "1" ){
}
else{
}
```

When I try `echo returnCode` the script prints "1" on the console, but it always goes into the else-part. What is wrong with the comparing?

Comment: Is `returnCode` of type `String`?

Comment: The documentation says: readFile: Read file from workspace

Reads a file from a relative path (with root in current directory, usually workspace) and returns its content as a plain string.

So I think it should be a string?

Comment: Is it possible that you have some hidden chars in the `return` file, like a newline character? Maybe try to `trim()` the `returnCode` string.

Answer (score 6):

One of the comments mentioned using "trim()".  This is very likely the problem.

Whenever I print strings while debugging, I always print them like this:

```
println "label[${variable}]"
```

If you see in the output the value on one line and the "]" on the next line (or just with additional spaces), that shows that you have to "trim()" the value.

Answer (score 1):

I to have faced same issue. The problem is with new line or space character. For example:

```
status = getstat()
if (status == "started"){
  println("in if")
} else {
  println("in else")
}

def getstat() {
  def out = new StringBuilder(), err = new StringBuilder()
    status = 'echo started'.execute()
  status.consumeProcessOutput(out, err)
  println "out> $out err> $err"
  println(out)
  return out
}
```

o/p is :

```
out> started
 err> 
started

in else
```

Now just change the return value to

```
return out.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");
```

Now o/p is:

```
out> started
 err> 
started

in if
```

Answer (score -2):

PLS check this one

```
node ('master'){
    def returnCode = 1
    println (returnCode)

    if( returnCode == 1 ) {
        sh 'echo 1 !!'
    }
    else{
        sh 'echo not 1 !!!'
    }
}
```